# Add-in to get Message Headers

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, outlook-web-addins, email-headers

I'm trying to create an Outlook Add-in that works to get just the Message Headers.

I already know how to get the sender, subject, id, dateTimes, etc. But I need the Hop Details (IP addresses, servers...).

I found one Add-in (made it by Stephene Griffin from MS) that shows a lot of information about an Outlook Mail (Message Headers included). I've taken a look at the code and it seems it would be hard to modify since it is a very complex project.

I also tried this, but it doesn't works.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders.getAsync(["header1", "header2"], callback);

function callback(asyncResult) {
  var dictionary = asyncResult.value;
  var header1_value = dictionary["header1"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The internetHeaders API only returns headers that are set by the API (before sending the message), plus headers that are stamped on the message as a MAPI property, according to the comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518119/cant-get-most-email-headers-in-outlook-addin-api))

Getting other properties is possible via the [Get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#request-2) REST API, which [can be called from an add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api).

The REST API call looks like this:

`GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/<messageId>/?$select=internetMessageHeaders`

I believe the hop details you are looking for are in the `Received` property, which can have multiple occurrences.

Some headers, like `From`, are not returned under `internetMessageHeaders` but are available under a different a property on the [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0).